# I can't vote anymore today but I only voted 39 times

Tags: bug, voting

I can't vote anymore today, but I only voted 39 times. What is happening here?

Comment: It happened again today. Still no Vox Populi badge...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[The Complete Rate-Limiting Guide](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/164899/the-complete-rate-limiting-guide)

> you get 10 Q-votes and 30 QA-votes per day. When you vote on a question, you'll use a Q-vote, and on an answer, you'll use a QA-vote. If you run out of Q-votes, you can continue voting on questions, but you'll be using QA-votes. However, once you have only 5 QA-votes left, you'll be blocked from using your Q-votes and all of your remaining voting for the day will use your QA-votes.

You voted on too many answers, basically.